# Adding “password” type to Google Apps Script inputBox in Google drive add on

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-addon

Is it possible to assign "password" type to the Google apps script input box so that text doesn't show?
My code is working fine except the input field is just text box and displays the text rather than "......"

```
 var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  section.addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName('Password')
    .setTitle('Password'));
```

Comment: Go [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225756/adding-password-type-to-google-apps-script-inputbox), I think it has what you are looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding "password" type to Google Apps Script inputBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225756/adding-password-type-to-google-apps-script-inputbox)

Comment: Hello @Twinkle, does the suggested post answer your question? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13, It is not working in case of google drive add on. It might work for spreadsheets only!

Comment: @Twinkle what exactly from the code there is not working? Are you getting any errors? Cheers!

Comment: @EliJohnson, We are trying for google drive add on but the post you've suggested works for spreadsheets or docs.